# Fedora 35: Switch back to stock kernel?

Tags: fedora, linux-kernel

A few months ago I built a new machine and installed Fedora on it.  At the time, 5.15 was the latest "stock" kernel, but I needed some of the Alder Lake fixes/improvements from 5.16 and 5.17, so I followed the instructions [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Kernel_Vanilla_Repositories) and switched to the Vanilla 5.17 kernel.

Now that 5.17 has passed out into the "stock" world (it's been a few weeks now, I'm just a bit behind) I'd like to switch back to the stock build.  Unfortunately, all of the instructions I've seen require booting into a stock kernel first, and that's no longer an option as a series of 5.17-rc Vanilla builds have pushed out all stock kernels.

So my question is: how do I get a stock kernel back on my machine?

Comment: When you boot, aren't "stock" kernels offered as choice?

Comment: No, that's the part where I said "that's no longer an option as a series of 5.17-rc Vanilla builds have pushed out all stock kernels"

Comment: What happens after `sudo dnf install  kernel-5.16.20-200.fc35`?

Comment: oh well, stock kernel 5.17.4 came out so dnf happily upgraded the Vanilla "5.17.0" kernel.  So I guess it's solved now >.>